# Search field doesn't seem to appear in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have the following code in my view file

```
<%= form_tag search_path, class: "form-inline", method: :get do %>
<div class="input-group input-group-lg">
<% if params[:query].present? %>
 <div class="input-group-btn">
   <%= link_to "clear", search_path, class: "btn btn-default" %></div>
<%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query], id: "univ_search", autocomplete: "on"%>
<div class="input-group-btn">
 <%= submit_tag "Search", class: "btn btn-primary"%>
  </div>
  </div>
<%end%>
 <%end%>
```

However, it doesn't show any text field or buttons in the browser. Can someone suggest a way to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the condition

```
<% if params[:query].present? %>
```

is preventing the view.